# Getting undefined in AJAX and LARAVEL

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

im getting undefined problem in getting data from my laravel and ajax trials.

here's my ajax

```
var data = $(this).serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ route('ajaxdata.getactivities') }}",
    type: "GET",
    datatType: 'json',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    error: function (data) {
        console.log('AJAX call Failed');
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('AJAX call success');
        $('#test').append('Add' + data.id); //data.id is showing undefined. if it is only data it doesnt show anything but AJAX call success
    },
});
```

Here's my route

```
Route::get('ajaxdata/getactivities', 'AjaxdataController@getactivities')
    ->name('ajaxdata.getactivities');
```

Here's my controller function

```
function getactivities()
{
    $activities = Activity::orderby('id', 'asc')->get();

    return view('student.ajaxdata', compact('activities'));
}
```

Comment: try `console.log(data)` and see whether it contains any data

Comment: you are not returning any id from controller.

Comment: @akshithDayanand it doesnt contain anything but the ajax call is a success.

Comment: @AkashKumarVerma what do you mean? can you point out it in my code thanks

Comment: @MichaelBenGabriel If it doesn't contain anything, it means that there is an issue in your controller

Comment: Are you trying to upload something?

Comment: trying to get the data from mysql @EmekaOkafor

Comment: Why are you returning a view?

Comment: i want to show data from the db @Thomas im new to ajax to laravel so i need some help . my console.log(data) shows onlin {"activities":[]}

Comment: the easiest way i can help you out is to find out the ajax error code, in your error function do something like this, console.log(data.status), also do console.log(data.responseText), the second part will show your controller error if you have one.

Comment: For returning json data you don't need / should not return a view, but just return the collection and Laravel will convert it for you. Add the right headers foor jquery as well.

Comment: Why are you returning a view from your controller action? Also why are you trying to access `data.id` in your AJAX success handler when your action would probably return an array of results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Let us Rewrite the whole stuff

```
var data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('ajaxdata.getactivities') }}",//if this page 

// does not end with something.blade.php, it will not render your url, i.e if you have seperate .js file, consider rewriting this line, probably like so
   // $url=$(this).attr('action');
            type:"GET",
            datatType : 'json',
            data: data,

            error: function (data)
      {
        console.log('AJAX call Failed');
      },
        success: function(data)
      {
        console.log('AJAX call success');
        $('#test').append('Add' + data.id); //data.id is showing undefined. if it `is only data it doesnt show anything but AJAX call success`
    },
        })
```

It looks like you want to return the view, you will need to render it like so

```
function getactivities()
    {    
    $activities = Activity::orderBy('id','asc')->get();
    $data=view('student.ajaxdata', compact('activities'))->render();
return response()->json(['html'=>$data]);
    }
```

and access it in your ajax success as

```
console.log(data.success)// this will return the page with the value and not the values alone.
```

but if you do not want to return the page, then work it out like so

```
function getactivities()
{    
$activities = Activity::orderBy('id','asc')->get();
//return view('student.ajaxdata', compact('activities'));
return response()->json(['$data'=>$activities]);
//remember the data returned here is a collection since you are using a `get() method, you cannot do data.id in your ajax without iterating over it, if you plan to return just a row, then rewrite this line`
$activities = Activity::orderBy('id','asc')->first();
}
```

and access it same way in ajax success.

```
    console.log(data)

$data: Array(3)
0:
ActionDescription: ""
ActivityDate: "0000-00-00"
ActivityID: "1"
ActivityName: "Training"
ActivityTime: "00:00:00"
ActivityTypeID: ""
Location: "Moa"
QRCode: ""
created_at: null
event_id: 1
id: 1
updated_at: null
__proto__: Object
1: {id: 3, ActivityName: "Bruno", Location: "NY", ActionDescription: "A", ActivityDate: "0000-00-00", …}
2:
ActionDescription: "Training"
ActivityDate: "0000-00-00"
ActivityID: null
ActivityName: "Bad Blood"
ActivityTime: "12:00:00"
ActivityTypeID: null
Location: "SM Trinoma"
QRCode: null
created_at: "2019-04-11 05:38:30"
event_id: 2
id: 2
updated_at: "2019-04-11 05:38:30"
__proto
```

Comment: it is now showing in the console.log(data) 
but it is not showing in my append 
$('#test').append('Add' + data.ActivityName); it shows Add[object object]

Comment: check my comment above and get back please

Comment: since you are appending data.id, take my second approach on the controller, thats the one without rendering of the view

Comment: also you are using a get(), it is returning a collection, you will need to iterate over it or change you call to this $activities = Activity::orderBy('id','asc')->first();

Comment: yes im using your second approach. done with data,status and reponsetext. it outputs undefined

Comment: it looks like your url is having issues, please what of the status code, definitely it should have a code

Comment: undefined
ajaxdata:202 {$data: {…}}$data: ActionDescription: ""ActivityDate: "0000-00-00"ActivityID: "1"ActivityName: "Training"ActivityTime: "00:00:00"ActivityTypeID: ""Location: "Moa"QRCode: ""created_at: nullevent_id: 1id: 1updated_at: null__proto__: Object__proto__: Object
ajaxdata:203 undefined
ajaxdata:204 undefined
heres the console data is ok i dont know what is wrong

Comment: Can you try to log data only?As `ctivity::orderBy('id','asc')->get()` may returning collection here so better log data ,than do something like below

success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function() {
               $('#test').append('Add' + data.id);
            });
        }

Comment: can you do console.log(data) only and find you if you are trying to access a null value from database

Comment: using console.log(data) it does not return null it shows the data in array but when using the data.object it is undefined @EmekaOkafor

Comment: then the error is your javascript, there is no such thing as id in the returned array please show the returned array data

Comment: from your array, please do something like data[0].id

Answer (score 1):

You have typo in `orderby` in your controller:

```
$activities = Activity::orderBy('id','asc')->get();
```

And ajax does not return view, try to:

```
return compact('activities');
```

Also data from response is array of activities and you can't take id of array. Try `data[0].id` for example.

Comment: even if i change it to orderBy @sergey nothings change

Comment: i see. the console.log() show only {"activities":[]}

Comment: Hm, seems like your activities table is empty

Comment: I'd suggest returning json though; return `response()->json(['activities => $activities]);`

Comment: `orderby` and `orderBy` should both work as PHP is case insensitive. Even `oRdeRbY` should work :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to log data only?

As `Activity::orderBy('id','asc')->get()` may be returning collection here so better log data ,than do something like below success:

```
`success: function (data) {
    { 
        $.each(data, function() 
        { 
            console.log(data);  //shows the data in array 
            $('#test').append('Add' + data.id); }); 
        }
    }`
```

Comment: it is working if i do data[0].id, shows only 1 data but wihtout it is undefined and does not show all data @svikramjeet

Comment: Adding each on data

Comment: already add it doesnt work though
$.each(data, function(key, value) 
        { 
        console.log(data);
        $('#test').append('Add' + value.ActivityName); 
        
        });

Comment: Add undefined is the output

Comment: var data = $(this).serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ route('ajaxdata.getactivities') }}",
    type: "GET",
    datatType: 'json',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data); // is it still showing undefined here?
    },
});

Comment: the console.log(data) doesnt shows undefined it show the data in array. my problem is when i call the specific field like data.id, data.ActivityName it shows sundefined

Comment: $.each(data, function(key, value) { console.log(value.id); })

@MichaelBenGabriel

Comment: thats my problem $.each(data, function(key, value) { $('#test').append('Add' + value.id); })  -- this line of code returns undefined

Comment: Please share the output of following 
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
 console.log(key); 
 console.log(value); 
})

Comment: see my question above image thats console.log(value.id); 
            console.log(value); 
            console.log(key);

Comment: output value.id is undefined, value is the actual data, key outputs $data only

Answer (score 1):

with all that hassle using $.each doesnt work for looping the data, so I use for to output the data. Here's my working code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = $(this).serialize(); 
    $.ajax({ url: "{{ route('ajaxdata.getactivities') }}", 
    method: "get",
    dataType:"JSON", 
    data: data, 
    // cache: false, 
    // processData: false, 
    success: function (data) 
    { 
        $.each(data,function(key,value) { 

            for(var x=0; x < value.length; x++){
            console.log(value[x].ActivityName);

            $('#activities').append($('<option>', {value:value[x].id, text:value[x].ActivityName}));
           }
        })
      }, 
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, You are sending view(Blade file) rather than data.
send json formated data which is easy for you to access data in javascript.
Why dont you use `return response()->json(['status'=>200,'payload'=>$ourdata]);`
And also `orderby` is like `orderBy`

Like the following

`$activities = Activity::orderBy('id','asc')->get();
  return response()->json(['status'=>200,'payload'=>$activities]);`